# How to get an empty vector when requesting a sequence from `a` to `b < a`?

Tags: r, sequence

In R, `a:b` returns the vector `c(a, a-1, ..., b)` when `b < a`. Some programming languages such as Julia and Haskell would return the empty vector instead. Is there something in R like `a:b` but which returns the empty vector when `b < a`? Otherwise I have to test whether `a <= b` and this is not very convenient.

Comment: You could make your own... `if(a < b) NULL else a:b` doesn't seem too much of an inconvenience to me at least.

Comment: You will have to create a class for that. Note that every language has its syntax, definitions and meaning. You now want to get an empty vector when `b < a`, someone else would want the reversed vector when `b < a`. These two options are mutually exclusive and only one could be implemented. I am in a way convinced that in Julia and Heskell, if one wants a reversed vector, they wont use `a:b` when `b<a`. Similarly in R, when one wants an empty vector they will have to go about it in a different manner